# Get synonyms of a taxon without repetition

Tags: sparql, synonym

I'm querying [this endpoint](http://202.45.139.84:10035/catalogs/fao/repositories/agrovoc#query) to exctract taxons with their synonyms, I want the end result to be a JSON file containing the taxons URIs and their names along with the synonyms:

```
{ 
    TAXON_URI: [TAXON_NAME, TAXON_SYN1, .....], 
    ...
}
```

The query I used:

```
PREFIX ns0: <http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrontology#>
PREFIX skosxl: <http://www.w3.org/2008/05/skos-xl#>

SELECT ?taxon_name_uri ?taxon_name ?taxon_synonym
WHERE{
  # select only 'Taxonomic terms for plants' !!
  ?taxon_name_uri ns0:hasTermType "Taxonomic terms for plants".
  ?taxon_name_uri ns0:hasSynonym ?taxon_synonym_uri.
  ?taxon_name_uri skosxl:literalForm ?taxon_name.
  ?taxon_synonym_uri skosxl:literalForm ?taxon_synonym.
  FILTER (lang(?taxon_synonym) = 'en' || lang(?taxon_synonym) = 'fr')
}
ORDER BY ?taxon_name_uri
LIMIT 100
```

The result seems logical but that's not exactly what I wanted, here's is a sample illustrating my problem:

```
taxon_name_uri                  taxon_name              taxon_synonym
------------------------------------------------------------------------
agrovoc:/xl_en_1299492690497    "Plantago ovata"        "Plantago minima"
agrovoc:/xl_en_1299492690497    "Plantago ovata"        "Plantago gooddingii"
agrovoc:/xl_en_1299492690497    "Plantago ovata"        "Plantago brunnea"
agrovoc:/xl_en_1299492690497    "Plantago ovata"        "Plantago fastigiata"
agrovoc:/xl_en_1299492690497    "Plantago ovata"        "Plantago insularis"
agrovoc:/xl_en_1299492691630    "Plantago brunnea"      "Plantago ovata"
agrovoc:/xl_en_1299492691706    "Plantago fastigiata"   "Plantago ovata"
agrovoc:/xl_en_1299492691791    "Plantago gooddingii"   "Plantago ovata"
agrovoc:/xl_en_1299492691878    "Plantago insularis"    "Plantago ovata"
agrovoc:/xl_en_1299492691969    "Plantago minima"       "Plantago ovata"
```

This is the JSON I got based on the result above:

```
{
    "http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/xl_en_1299492690497": [
        "Plantago ovata",
        "Plantago minima",
        "Plantago gooddingii",
        "Plantago brunnea",
        "Plantago fastigiata",
        "Plantago insularis"
    ],
    "http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/xl_en_1299492691630": [
        "Plantago brunnea",
        "Plantago ovata"
    ],
    "http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/xl_en_1299492691706": [
        "Plantago fastigiata",
        "Plantago ovata"
    ],
    "http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/xl_en_1299492691791": [
        "Plantago gooddingii",
        "Plantago ovata"
    ],
    "http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/xl_en_1299492691878": [
        "Plantago insularis",
        "Plantago ovata"
    ],
    "http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/xl_en_1299492691969": [
        "Plantago minima",
        "Plantago ovata"
    ]
}
```

I got a lot of duplicats here and I'm interested only in the first 5 lines of the SPARQL query result where `taxon_name` is `Plantago ovata`, based on this idea, the JSON will look as follows:

```
{
    "http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/xl_en_1299492690497": [
        "Plantago ovata",
        "Plantago minima",
        "Plantago gooddingii",
        "Plantago brunnea",
        "Plantago fastigiata",
        "Plantago insularis"
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: `?taxon_name_uri ns0:scientificNameOf [] .`?

Comment: @StanislavKralin, Thank you ! That was quick ! I also added `DISTINCT` to the query because I got some duplicates.